# Overriding Method Used in Base Class Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have the following:

```
class Parent:

    @classmethod
    def add_2(cls, number):

        plus_1 = cls.add_1(number)
        plus_2 = cls.add_1(number)
        return plus_2

    def add_1(cls, number):

        return number + 1

class Child(Parent):

    @classmethod
    def add_1(cls, number):

        return number + 2

Child.add_1(5)
Child.add_2(5)
```

I want Child.add_2(5) to return 9, but it returns 7. Can anyone explain why this behavior is occurring? Its easy enough to fix it by overriding add_2 as well in the child class, but it seems overly clunky.

Comment: Is the lack of a `@classmethod` decorator for `Parent.add_1` intentional?

Comment: `return plus_1 + plus_2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're expecting `Child.add_2(5)` to return **9** based on the fact that:

- `Child.add_1` adds **2** to the argument it receives (initially **5**)
- `Child.add_2` (inherited from `Parent`) calls `Child.add_1` twice (so it would make sense that 5 + 2 + 2 = 9)

The problem is in `Parent.add_2`:

```
plus_1 = cls.add_1(number)
plus_2 = cls.add_1(number)
```

`cls.add_1` is called twice, but the result of the 1<sup>st</sup> call (`plus_1`) is ignored, and the 2<sup>nd</sup> call starts from `number` which is **5**, resulting **7**.

To correct the problem (which I think it's a typo due to copy/paste), modify `cls.add_1` 2<sup>nd</sup> call to:

```
plus_2 = cls.add_1(plus_1)
```

to take the result of the 1<sup>st</sup> call into account.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Second call should be plus_2 = cls.add_1(plus_1). Purely the result of a typo! Whoops